# How to send OSSec Notification to a HTTP URL

Tags: intrusion-detection

Currently I see just email notification which can be sent for alerts in OSSec. Is there any way to make an http call in case of an alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any direct way to send ossec notification to webhook URL. But, I got this working with help of logstash, which we use for log parsing and indexing. I added a logstash output with following configuration:

```
output {
  if [type] == "ossec_alert" {
    http {
      http_method => "post"
      url => "https://mythhpwebhook.com?key=1234"
      content_type => "application/json"
      mapping => ["Subject", "OSSEC Alert: %{signature}", "Message", "%{message}"]
    }
  }
}
```

Not: message and signature are variable from filter applied to ossec input.

Answer (score 0):

i found, that you can send ossec notification with active responces: look at this [example](http://dcid.me/blog/2009/04/ossec-to-twitter/) and this [ossec-tweeter.sh](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/blob/master/active-response/ossec-tweeter.sh)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Comment: Thank you for you attention!
I've add sources for example of http call in case of an alert?

Comment: well ... the solution is still in the links only, isn't it? Could you add the relevant parts of those?

Comment: Nope, i can't do this.
Due to my contract i can't post any details.
But links to another resourses, as i think, i still can post.